# Is "is" or is "are" preferred here?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which of the following  is "more better":

*Here **is** a handful of snippets...*

...or:

*Here **are** a handful of snippets...*

? "Snippets" are plural, but "a handful" is singular, so I'm divided between which sounds better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a matter of flow or sounding better, but of grammar, specifically of subject/verb agreement.

The subject is "handful", which is singular.  The verb therefore needs to take the singular form, "is".  Being intransitive, of course, there is no object.  "of snippets" is a modifier of "handful", describing it or its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go for the second option, "here are a handful of snippets." I feel it flows better using "are" than "is"